# Compare bytearrays in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript, compare, arrays

I've an image (JPEG) converted to a ByteArray in ActionScript. The SWF loads another image: I want to know if the loaded image is identical to the one I converted to a ByteArray. Is it possibile/safe to compare two ByteArrays as they were two strings? Or is it any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible (have you tried it?) but I would compare the images instead (i.e. using [BitmapData.compare](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29)) since it's what matters (different jpeg algorithms result in different bytes, but almost identical images). Plus, comparing the images you could set quite a "natural" threshold of similarity.

Comment: Hi Cay, I did not try because I thought I could not interpret well the result (if you compare other data types, eg Objects or Arrays the comparison goes not as "deep" as you may think). Thanks for the BitmapData compare tip!   :-)